# Constraint on DATEDIFF in sql query

Tags: mysql, datediff

I am working on sql assignment and got stuck at applying constraint on DATEDIFF.
My query is like..

```
select   *,DATEDIFF('$add_date_start',submitted_date) as d1,DATEDIFF('$add_date_end',submitted_date) as d2 from table where DATEDIFF('$add_date_start',submitted_date)<=0
```

I have also tried

```
select   *,DATEDIFF('$add_date_start',submitted_date) as d1,DATEDIFF('$add_date_end',submitted_date) as d2 from table where 'conditions 'HAVING d1<=0
```

Both of the queries showing 0 results.. 
All I have to do is put constraint on DATEDIFF to select on the basis on that.

The results are fine when i put condition in php using mysqli_fetch_array,something like...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result){ if($row['d1'] <=0){ ///code } }
```

Any help will be great.. Thank You

Comment: instead of `from table where 'conditions 'HAVING d1<=0` simply do `from table HAVING d1<=0`, also are you sure that you want d1<=0 and not d1>=0? d1<=0 means you want date_start to be later than submitted_date

Comment: yeah i have two conditions one is >0 and second is <0 .. conditions are other constraint on different columns..

Comment: Your first query also seems fine, first check that query after passing variable field value and check results..as I am getting correct data by following query "SELECT id,DATEDIFF('2015-06-16 00:00:00',NOW()) FROM mytable WHERE DATEDIFF('2015-06-16 00:00:00',NOW())<=0;"